# Undefined label in Lua

Tags: lua

The following code has undefined label room3. How could I fix this error?

```
function room1 ()
    local move = io.read()
    if move == "south" then goto room3
    elseif move == "east" then return room2()
    else
        print("invalid move")
        return room1()   -- stay in the same room
    end
end

function room2 ()
    local move = io.read()
    if move == "south" then return room4()
    elseif move == "west" then return room1()
    else
        print("invalid move")
        return room2()
    end
end

::room3:: 
do
    local move = io.read()
    if move == "north" then return room1()
    elseif move == "east" then return room4()
    else
        print("invalid move")
        goto room3
    end
end

function room4 ()
    print("congratulations!")
end

-- We start the game with a call to the initial room:

room1()
```

On the other hand, this code works perfectly:

```
goto room1

::room1:: do
    local move = io.read()
    if move == "south" then goto room3
    elseif move == "east" then return room2()
    else
        print("invalid move")
        goto room1
    end
end

::room2:: do
    local move = io.read()
    if move == "south" then goto room4
    elseif move == "wast" then goto room1
    else
        print("invalid move")
        return room2()
    end
end

::room3:: do
    local move = io.read()
    if move == "north" then goto room1
    elseif move == "east" then goto room4
    else
        print("invalid move")
        goto room3
    end
end

::room4:: do
    print "Congratulations, you won!"
end
```

Comment: As I recall labels are only valid in scope. `room1` doesn't have the `room3` label in its scope.

Comment: Can you double check the edited questions? In the working example, room3 label definition is outside of room1 definition

Comment: Why are you using `goto` at all?

Comment: I don't like using goto like in the "working" example. Looks pretty dirty to me.

Answer (score 2):

`room3` is not visible within `room1()`'s scope.

From the Lua reference:

> A **label is visible** in the entire block where it is defined, **except**
>   inside nested blocks where a label with the same name is defined and
>   **inside nested functions**. A goto may jump to any visible label as long
>   as it does not enter into the scope of a local variable.

Therefor you cannot jump into a function or out of one using `goto`.
You can't jump into a function because the label would be inside the function so it is invisible outside. And you cannot jump out of a function because you can't see outside labels from inside a function.

I would rather use a recursive function call. I see no reason why you should implement `room3` different from the other rooms.

```
function room3()

    local move = io.read()
    if move == "north" then return room1()
    elseif move == "east" then return room4()
    else
        print("invalid move")
        return room3()
    end
end
```

Please also note that your working example will cause an error when you go east in `room1` as `function room2` is not defined.